# Ubuntu 19.10 - Changing default lock screen background

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, lock-screen, gdm

Regardless of what my lock screen background is configured to be, the default lock screen background is still the default eoan ermine. My own lock screen only shows up when I explicitly lock my session (e.g. by `Super + L`). How can I change it to something else?

Note that I am not talking about the login screen (I already have answers for that). I'm talking about that thing that normally covers the login screen, and usually has a clock on it.